# How can I generate the buttons and connect them to different functions?

Tags: python, button, pyqt, pyqt5, signals

I've created a search engine in PyQt5, using the code below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QLineEdit, QLabel, QScrollArea, QMainWindow,
    QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QCompleter, QPushButton
)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

tlist = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4']

class Label(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Label, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.lbl = QLabel(self.name)
        self.lbl.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Preview")
        self.btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100,100))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printsignal)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

    def show(self):
        for labels in [self, self.lbl]:
            labels.setVisible(True)

    def hide(self):
        for labels in [self, self.lbl]:
            labels.setVisible(False)

    def printsignal(self):
        print("clicked")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.controls = QWidget()
        self.controlsLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.widgets = []
        for name in tlist:
            item = Label(name)
            self.controlsLayout.addWidget(item)
            self.widgets.append(item)
        spacer = QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.controlsLayout.addItem(spacer)
        self.controls.setLayout(self.controlsLayout)
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.controls)
        self.searchbar = QLineEdit()
        self.searchbar.textChanged.connect(self.update_display)
        self.completer = QCompleter(tlist)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.searchbar.setCompleter(self.completer)
        container = QWidget()
        containerLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.searchbar)
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        container.setLayout(containerLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Search Engine')

    def update_display(self, text):
        for widget in self.widgets:
            if text.lower() in widget.name.lower():
                widget.show()
            else:
                widget.hide()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem I have is, all the buttons share the same function and I don't know how to make them have different signals, as they are generated automatically. Basically, if I run the code it will show up like
this:
[image: this] and when I press any of the buttons, it will print "clicked" (as in printsignal function). What I want is a different function for each button. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: 1) what should happen instead of printing the message? 2) the overrides of `show` and `hide` are useless, remove them, as QWidget already provides it.

Comment: 1) Each button should print their name (e.i.: if i press the button next to thing1, it should print "clicked thing1", if i press the button next to thing2, it should print "clicked thing2" and so on).
2) i didn't know that but it works so thank you

Comment: Since you have access to `self.lbl` from within `Label.printsignal`, you could use something like `print(f"clicked {self.lbl.text()}")`.

Comment: similar problem was yesterday - in function you can use `self.sender().text()` to get `text` from `Button` which generated signal. But if you create own widget `Label` then you can get directly values in your widget `Label` and every widget will get own value.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use `self.sender().text()` to get text from `QButton` which generated signal.

But because you create own widget `Label` with `QButton` and `QLabel` and you want text from label so you can get directly `self.name`

```
def printsignal(self):
    print("clicked", self.name)
```

eventually `self.lbl.text()`

```
def printsignal(self):
    print("clicked", self.lbl.text())
```

---

Working code.

I removed `show()`, `hide()` because you don't need it

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QLineEdit, QLabel, QScrollArea, QMainWindow,
    QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QCompleter, QPushButton
)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

tlist = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4']


class Label(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.name = name

        self.lbl = QLabel(self.name)
        self.lbl.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Preview")
        self.btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100,100))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printsignal)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

    def printsignal(self):
        print("clicked", self.name)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.controls = QWidget()
        self.controlsLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.widgets = []
        for name in tlist:
            item = Label(name)
            self.controlsLayout.addWidget(item)
            self.widgets.append(item)

        spacer = QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.controlsLayout.addItem(spacer)
        self.controls.setLayout(self.controlsLayout)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.controls)

        self.searchbar = QLineEdit()
        self.searchbar.textChanged.connect(self.update_display)

        self.completer = QCompleter(tlist)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.searchbar.setCompleter(self.completer)

        container = QWidget()
        containerLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.searchbar)
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        container.setLayout(containerLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Search Engine')

    def update_display(self, text):
        for widget in self.widgets:
            if text.lower() in widget.name.lower():
                widget.show()
            else:
                widget.hide()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```